# Statistical significance in multiple groups

Tags: statistics, confidence, pvalue

What is the most appropriate test to validate significance in the case I'm comparing multiple different groups? e.g.

I have different groups of ages (teenager, young, adult, elderly) and a conversion rate related to each of them in my website. How can I validate the differences in the conversion rates from a statistical point of view?

```
class      size    conversion 
teenager   1000        3%
young       700       3.3%
adult       800       4.7%
elderly     300       2.3%
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use statistical significance formula for that.
Example of explanation here: https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/how-to-calculate-statistical-significance